# How to plot characters in Bokeh

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I have a pandas DataFrame in which all the values are English alphabets or empty string "". My goal is to a) plot these alphabets by taking column index as X axis and the row index as Y axis (scatter plot)  and 
b)to have control over the spacing in the direction of X axis so that they are not spaced wide apart .

I have been able to plot glyphs (circle for ex.) at the desired coordinates but not the alphabets (as they appear in the DataFrame). And also these circles were spaced wide apart as X axis has 0,1,2,3...  . X axis can be made categorical also instead of integers if that provides a simple/better solution.

```py
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource,Range1d #FactorRange

output_file("plot_text.html",title="plot_text")
# creating the DataFrame
d = {0:["A","A","A","D","D","C","E"],
    1:["B","","B","C","D","E","E"],
    2:["","","F","F","G","","H"],
    3:["","","","","","H","H"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d,index=range(800,100,-100))
list1_x = []
list1_y = []
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    for j in range(len(df.index)):
        if df.iloc[j,i]=="": # excluding the "" appearance
            continue
        else:
            list1_x.append(df.columns[i])
            list1_y.append(df.index[j])
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x = list1_x,y = list1_y))
fig = figure(plot_height=500, plot_width=1100,
    tools="pan,xwheel_zoom,reset,save,crosshair,box_zoom",
    active_drag='pan',
    active_scroll='xwheel_zoom',
    x_range=Range1d(-5, 100, bounds="auto"),
    y_range=Range1d(-100, 1200, bounds="auto")
    )
fig.circle(x= 'x',y='y',color = "blue",size =10,source = source)
show(fig)
```

As mentioned earlier, the above code plots a single glyph(circle in this case) - which is not what I want and moreover I have absolutely no idea as to how to achieve control over scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a list from the data you want to plot with the same length as the others in the columndatasource then add it to your source. You can disable your circles if you want just the characters otherwise both will be plotted, you also should consider using hoover which is a very good way to add interaction to a plot.
I used LabelSet to map the coords of your data, you also can play with offsets to adjust the spacing as you mentioned.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource,Range1d, LabelSet #FactorRange
import itertools
output_notebook()

output_file("plot_text.html",title="plot_text")
# creating the DataFrame
d = {0:["A","A","A","D","D","C","E"],
    1:["B","","B","C","D","E","E"],
    2:["","","F","F","G","","H"],
    3:["","","","","","H","H"]}
#convert dict to a single list to match the length in your 
#source(ColumnDataSource)
d1 = list(d.values())
d_letters = list(itertools.chain(*d1))
#I tried to remove your nan values, but it didnt work, I did it manually but 
#here is the code to do so
d2 = [x for x in d_letters if d_letters != ''] # [x for x in d_letters if 
#d_letters != 'nan']
d_ = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'B', 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'E', 'F', 
'F', 'G', 'H', 'H', 'H']
#len(d_) 19 as x and y


df = pd.DataFrame(d,index=range(800,100,-100))
list1_x = []
list1_y = []
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    for j in range(len(df.index)):
        if df.iloc[j,i]=="": # excluding the "" appearance
            continue
        else:
            list1_x.append(df.columns[i])
            list1_y.append(df.index[j])
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x = list1_x,y = list1_y, x1=d_))
fig = figure(plot_height=500, plot_width=1100,
    tools="pan,xwheel_zoom,reset,save,crosshair,box_zoom",
    active_drag='pan',
    active_scroll='xwheel_zoom',
    x_range=Range1d(-5, 100, bounds="auto"),
    y_range=Range1d(-100, 1200, bounds="auto")
    )
fig.circle(x= 'x',y='y',color = "blue",size =10,source = source)

#create labels
labels = LabelSet(x='x', y='y', text='x1', level='glyph',
              x_offset=5, y_offset=5, source=source, render_mode='canvas')


fig.add_layout(labels)


show(fig)
```

Comment: d2 = [x for x in d_letters if x != '']  will remove all empty strings. Was not aware about LabelSet . But this is what I was looking for.